# Exp:resso Store - Using Datagrab to Import Excell File + Import Modifiers

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce, expresso, datagrab

Good Afternoon,

We're currently in a testing phase for a client who is looking to move to from xcart to a more developer friendly expressionengine / E-Commerce site with store preferably.

Does anyone have some best practices in mind?

Also, since the client is using FileMaker to sync stock levels on the site with their brick and motor locations POS, I was thinking that Datagrab would be a good solution, but realize that there would be issues with the "modifiers" and shipping weights.

Any thoughts on the best solution as well as any third-party developers that could assist if needed with the scripting for Datagrab?

Current client accounts and history are another bag... but really to get the initial test done I'll just need to get the initial test data to import correctly.

Hope this is detailed enough.

Best regards,

Troy

Answer (score 7):

I'm the author of DataGrab.

Support for 3rd party add-ons like Store is largely based on demand.

Initially I added basic support for Store because I needed it for one of my own projects, and then it got extended to add most of the extra fields (eg, stock and sale prices) when another developer needed it.

As you mention it does not currently support price modifiers, but I'd be happy to try and add support.

Answer (score 5):

Andrew Weaver extended DataGrab in the forums to support this I believe. Have a look at [his post](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/forums/viewthread/620/P15/#2096) for more info.

Like Justin said moving forward you'll need an extension to keep both databases synced.

Answer (score 2):

DataGrab does indeed have support for importing data into Store but I have not used it before so I am not to sure exactly what its limitations might be in terms of more complex entry data.

If you are wanting to sync data on a regular basis you would probably be better off with an extension leveraging the [store_order_complete_end](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/developers/extension_hooks.html#store-order-complete-end) and [store_inventory_datatable](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/developers/extension_hooks.html#store-inventory-datatable) extension hooks to sync the data between the 2 systems.